# Configuring Erlang plugin for Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, erlang, rebar

I am trying to set-up an Erlang project in IntelliJ 15. I am running windows.

I have built Rebar. trying `escript.exe "//rebar_path//" --version` returns the version number. Erlang also works on command line. In `Settings->Other-settings->Erlang External tools` I have the address of rebar file and IntelliJ detects the version number alright.

For my hello-world Erlang App, I have added an Erlang console application which runs fine and gives me

`D:/Program Files/erl7.2.1\bin\erl" -pa` `E:/Documents/Projects/Erlang_test/out/production/Erlang_test -pa` `E:/Documents/Projects/Erlang_test`

at the top. However attempting to call the functions gives me:

```
exception error: undefined function hello:hello2/0
```

It's as if compilation does not happen. I also tried setting up an "Erlang Rebar" Run configuration with compile as the command. It outputs:

```
*"D:\Program Files\erl7.2.1\bin\escript.exe"
E:\Documents\Projects\rebar_source\rebar c*
```

at the top, followed by the error:

```
escript: Error executing 'D:\Program': 193
```

What am I doing wrong?

**update**: I tried adding the rebar.cmd as an external tool to run it before the run configuration. After doing some research, I tried adding a rebar.config file with:

```
{sub_dirs, ["src" ] }.
```

to match the project structure.

Running the tool with `compile` on its own outputs: ([configuration page screenshot](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=23mrgxc&s=9#.VpLYglWLSUk))

```
==>src (compile)
==> Erlang_test (compile)
```

I was expecting to get: `Compiled src/hello.erl` but I neither get that, nor do I see any bean files created anywhere; and if I try running `hello:hello()` in the "Erlang console" run configuration gives me:

```
exception error: undefined function hello:hello2/0
```

Comment: https://github.com/ignatov/intellij-erlang/issues/470

Comment: That's not the problem I am having. I have added an update now.

Comment: There is something going on with Windows, IntelliJ IDEA and the Erlang plug-in for it. I have exactly the same issue, and it's pretty much reproducible. I'm not sure if folks from Linux/UN*X/Mac OS X have the same. As soon as you upgrade either IntelliJ IDEA to 15.x(with Erlang to 18.x) you are stuck! Whenever you try to do `Make`, `Make Module`, `Rebuild` to generate `.beam` files, nothing will be copied to the designated compiler output.